# BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 java android sketchware

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, sketchware

OnResponse code :

```
card_list = new Gson().fromJson(_response, new TypeToken>>(){}.getType());


if (card_list.size() > 5) {

    recyclerview1.setAdapter(new Recyclerview1Adapter(card_list));

}else{

SketchwareUtil.showMessage(getApplicationContext(), _response);

}
```

Json 200 Result like :

```
{

  "user": [

    {

      "id": "string",

      "address": "string",

      "contact": "string",

      "name": "string",

      "description": "string",

      "image_url": ""

    },{...},{...}

  ],

  "next": "string"

}
```

But have the error when opening an activity :

BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1

Please help me solve the code to retrieve json array to listmap for recyclerview in java android or sketchware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try your code this way:

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(_response);

    JSONArray userArray = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("user");
    
    card_list = new Gson().fromJson(userArray.toString(), new TypeToken<List<Map<String, String>>>(){}.getType());

    if (card_list.size() > 5) {
        recyclerview1.setAdapter(new Recyclerview1Adapter(card_list));
    } else {
        SketchwareUtil.showMessage(getApplicationContext(), "Not enough data for RecyclerView");
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    SketchwareUtil.showMessage(getApplicationContext(), "Error parsing JSON");
}
```

Comment: card_list = new Gson().fromJson(array.toString(), new TypeToken<List<Map<String, String>>>(){}.getType());
                                                       ^^^^^^^^^
TypeToken cannot be resolved to a type
----------
 card_list = new Gson().fromJson(array.toString(), new TypeToken<List<Map<String, String>>>(){}.getType());
                                                                                                ^^^^^^^
The method getType() is undefined for the type new TypeToken<List<Map<String,String>>>(){}

Comment: Thank you, That really helps to understand

Answer (score 0):

If you know the *JSON* *values*, you can be explicit.

Here is an example, where *s* is the *String*.

```java
Gson g = new Gson();
Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>> m
    = g.<Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>>>fromJson(s, Map.class);

System.out.println(m);
```

Output

```
{user=[{id=string, address=string, contact=string, name=string, description=string, image_url=}], next=string}
```

If not, define the *type-parameter* as *Object*, and cast the *Map* *value*.

```java
Gson g = new Gson();
Map<String, Object> m = g.<Map<String, Object>>fromJson(s, Map.class);

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Map<String, Object>> users = (List<Map<String, Object>>) m.get("user");
System.out.println(users);
```

Output

```
[{id=string, address=string, contact=string, name=string, description=string, image_url=}]
```

Comment: How to add all the key in user array to the listmap and view to the recyclerview

Comment: @inshanityina, just the _keys_, or the _values_ as well?

Answer (score 0):

The warning is there, Array was expected but found string, please show your response model for more context.
From your json response model class or model data class, user should be an array like below.

For Kotlin

```
data class Data (

 @SerializedName("user" ) var user : ArrayList<User> = arrayListOf(),
 @SerializedName("next" ) var next : String?         = null

 )


data class User (
  @SerializedName("id"          ) var id          : String? = null,
  @SerializedName("address"     ) var address     : String? = null,
  @SerializedName("contact"     ) var contact     : String? = null,
  @SerializedName("name"        ) var name        : String? = null,
  @SerializedName("description" ) var description : String? = null,
  @SerializedName("image_url"   ) var imageUrl    : String? = null
)
```

Java Should be:

```
 public class Data{
  public ArrayList<User> user;
  public String next;
 }

 public class User{
  public String id;
  public String address;
  public String contact;
  public String name;
  public String description;
  public String image_url;
 }
```

Comment: how to add the key and value to listmap and show to the recyclerview